# Leaflet Mouse Click acts differently than Trackpad Single Touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, leaflet

I am experiencing a really annoying bug and am hoping someone can help me with this.

When I create a popup in Leaflet using a **single touch with my Macbook Trackpad** it opens and stays open.

If I **click down on the Trackpad** or **use a mouse to click**, I can see the popup open but then it immediately disappears.

It seems to be completely removed when it disappears because the content in the div for 'leaflet-popup-pane' is removed.

I've done some searches for mouseup events to see if there is anything weird in the code base, but I haven't come across anything that would cause this issue.

Does anyone have any ideas on what's going on?

Here is the relevant code:

```
$map = $("#map")
    .on(touch.event.start, onMapTouchStart);

function onMapTouchStart(e) {
    var latLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(touch.getPoint(e));
    displayAttributes(latLng);
}

function displayAttributes(latLng) {
  var coordinates = selectedProjector.toGround(map.latLngToImagePoint(latLng));
  $.ajax("GetFeatureAttributes", {
      data: { x: coordinates[0], y: coordinates[1] },
      success: function (results) {
          var c = coordSys.inverse(coordinates);

          var popupHTML = [];
          $.each(results, function (index) {
              var attributes = JSON.parse(results[index].attributes);

              var layer = referenceFeatureLayers[results[index].referenceCollectionId];
              popupHTML.push("<div class='AttrBlock'>");
              popupHTML.push("<div class='AttrTitle' style='color: " + layer.color + "'>" + layer.name + "</div>");
              for (var key in attributes) {
                  if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                      popupHTML.push("<div class='AttrItem'><span class='AttrKey'>" + key + ":</span> " + attributes[key] + "</div>");
                  }
               }
               popupHTML.push("</div>");
           });

           var icon = L.icon( { iconUrl: 'Images/MarkerSmall.png' } );
           var marker = L.marker(latLng, { icon: icon }).addTo(map);

           var options =
               {
                   maxWidth: 300,
                   minWidth: 250,
                   maxHeight: 300,
                   autoPan: true,
                   closeButton: true,
                   autoPanPadding: [45, 90]
               };
           marker.bindPopup(popupHTML.join(""), options).openPopup();
       }
   });
}
```